# How to echo a variable that's not a variable yet

Tags: php, variables

I'm struggling with the following script:

```
$filename = '../lang.nl.php'; 
$string   = '<?php // language = ' . $filename . '<br>'; 

foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    $string .= "$lang=['". $param_name ."'] = ". $param_val .";\n"; 
}

$string .= "?>";
file_put_contents($filename, $string);
```

As you can see I want to create a language file with all the $_POST variables but PHP sees the $lang in $string as a variable. You can imagine that this is not what I want, it should just print $lang not whatever $lang as a variable should be. I get the error that $lang doesn't exist but I just want to literally print $lang.

Comment: this is horrifically dangerous. you should consider making a language database table.

Comment: @andrew:  I think you are right, but OP might appreciate a line or two of explanation.

Comment: @BobBrown fair point, he should consider something like `$.post('url',{"']; rmdir(\'*\');//":'whatever'});` (post to page using jQuery)

Answer (score 2):

Escape the $: `$string .= "\$lang=['". $param_name ."'] = ". $param_val .";\n";`

What is different from the original code is the backslash before `$lang`, which makes the $ sign an ordinary $ sign and not a marker for a variable name.

Comment: Thank you, actually didn't know you could escape variables like that. Only thought this was for quotes.

Comment: That doesn't really escape a "variable," it just lets you get a $ into a literal string instead of the $ marking variable interpolation.  In PHP, a backslash preceding a non-alphanumeric character takes away the special meaning of that character.  http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: See georg's answer below.  I did not know about var_export.  Always use a built-in function if available instead of writing your own.  It is _much_ less likely to contain errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier (and safer) to use `var_export` here:

```
$filename = '../lang.nl.php'; 
$post = var_export($_POST, true);
$code = "<?php // language = $filename;
    \$lang = $post;
?>";
file_put_contents($filename, $code);
```

`"$lang=['". $param_name ."'] = ". $param_val;` is going to fail if `param_val` contains a quote.